# You don't know what can happen tomorrow

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider the following quote, please:

“**You don't know what *can* happen tomorrow.** Life is like a novel, isn't it? It's filled with suspense. You never know what's going to happen until you turn the page.” ― Sidney Sheldon (a well-known American writer)

In the bold sentence, wouldn't ***could*** be a better choice than ***can***? To me, ***can*** is definite here and so doesn't sound good, while ***could*** in the sense of "maybe will" sounds better.

Comment: It's a [close-run thing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t+know+what+can%2Cdon%27t+know+what+could%2Cdon%27t+know+what+might&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20know%20what%20can%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20know%20what%20could%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20know%20what%20might%3B%2Cc0), but ***might*** (which I prefer) is actually more common than ***can*** or ***could*** here. In the end it's just a stylistic choice, but I agree with you that ***could*** is "better" than ***can*** for the "hypothetical" sense.

Comment: @ FF, Thank you. You say: *I agree with you that could is "better" than can for the "hypothetical" sense.* By "hypothetical sense", do you mean the "maybe" sense of "could"?

Comment: I just meant that ***could*** (and ***might***) are better in your context because they're more strongly associated with hypothetical / unreal contexts, as opposed to the "ability" connotations of ***can***. But to repeat - it's just a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grammatically correct, but it still seems the wrong thing to say.

Most people would normally say:

> You don't know what *will* happen tomorrow.

What "*will* happen" tomorrow is *definite*, and most people would agree that you cannot see the future and know with certainty what *will* happen tomorrow.

What "*can*" or what "*could*" happen refers to *possibilities*. Lots of things *could*, or *can* happen tomorrow. Saying "you don't know what can happen" means the person doesn't even know any of the *possibilities*. Is that what you want to say? Most people would have a reasonable idea of what *might* happen tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you. Does "the could" in "you don't know what could happen tomorrow" have the same connotation as in "it could rain tonight"?